# Firestore Security Rule to grant user read/write permissions on a document and its subcollection not working

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore collection named UserProfiles which stores the profile information for each user in individual documents. Each document is named with the user id of the user it belongs to. Each document also contains a number of sub collections as well. I'd like to make rules giving each user the ability to read and write his own document and sub collections under his document ONLY. However when a user tries to read his profile document I keep getting the following error message:

> Error getting documents: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}

Here is the rule I created:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    //grant users read and write access to anything under own profiles collection
    match /UserProfiles/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    //grant users read and write access to their own profile document
    match /UserProfiles/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Grateful if anyone could point out where I've gone wrong - Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry - here is the code on the client side in Swift:

```
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()

    if firebaseAuth.currentUser != nil {

      userUId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
      print("User id is \(String(describing: userUId))")

    } else {

      print("User is not currently logged in")

            return
    }

    //Getting my user info
    db.collection("UserProfiles").whereField("user_id", isEqualTo: self.userUId).getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
      if let error = error {

        print("Error getting documents in func viewWIllAppear with user id \(self.userUId): \(error)")

      } else {

        print("Successful db connection")
        for document in snapshot!.documents {

          self.myUserHandle = document["user_handle"]! as! String

          print("Retrieved user handle is \(self.myUserHandle)")


        }


      }


    }
```

And the Database structure is:

```
UserProfiles
    |
    |--FHEneuY3nron3Ns2Ndl1SGdg9Nsw
           |
           |--UserHistory
           |
           |--UserReports
           |
           |--UserLogs
```

Basically what I want to do with my rules is give a logged in user read and write permissions on his own profile document which is names with his user id (FHEneuY3nron3Ns2Ndl1SGdg9Nsw), and also on the subcollections beneath it (UserHistory, UserReports and UserLogs), but not allow users to read or write to other user's profile documents or their subcollections.

And then here is the result output to the console:

> user id is FHEneuY3nron3Ns2Ndl1SGdg9Nsw
>
> 2020-05-26 18:53:58.560680-0400 MealFleet[2495:1086294] 6.2.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at UserProfiles failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>   Error getting documents in func viewWIllAppear with user id FHEneuY3nron3Ns2Ndl1SGdg9Nsw: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}

UPDATE: Here is the corrected query thanks to Doug for pointing our my error:

```
db.collection("UserProfiles").document(self.userUId).getDocument() { (document, error) in
      if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data()
        self.myUserHandle = (dataDescription!["user_handle"] as? String)!
        print("Retrieved user handle is \(self.myUserHandle)")
      } else {
        print("Error getting documents in func viewWIllAppear with user id \(self.userUId): \(error)")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the client-side code you use to make the request

Comment: Without seeing the code that performs the query, we don't know if you're doing something wrong on the client.  Rules have no meaning if they are not paired with specific queries.  Please be sure that a user is signed in at the time of the query by checking the value of the Firebase Auth currenet user object.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I have added the rest of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query does not match your rules.  Your query is attempting to filter for all documents where the document field `user_id` is equal to some string `self.userUId`.  Your rules are requiring that a user may only access a single specific document in UserProfiles where the document ID matches their UID.  These are not the same thing at all.

If you want your code to access the user's specific document, then it should not use `whereField` at all.  It just needs to get the individual document using it ID.

```
db.collection("UserProfiles").document(self.userUId).getDocument()
```

See the documentation for [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness. Of Course! Thanks a lot Doug. I'll add the updated query in case it might help someone else.